Get the number of edges per island (and bool it with selection)
So I used the great solution of Markus von Broady to select edges of islands within the distance X to other islands. Now, it is a little embarrassing I cannot figure out how to get the number of edges within each island...
Blender Documentation for Geonodes defines islands, if I read it correctly, as any edge-connected vertices, so no faces actually required.
So: how do I get the number of edges within each face, and, getting them in a way so I can do a boolean AND to get the number of edges that also meet the distance criteria.

In the picture I drew the number of edges that meet both critera in red.
So in short: Give me the Number of [Edges per Face that meet the distance criteria (that is already calculated)]

Why?
This is about procedural city generation for laypeople (again). I would like to visualize, how encroached buildings are. Because european building typologies have different looks, which I am going to assign via Buildify by Pavel Olivia. Depending on the number of sides of the building that are encroached, you can decide if its a row, a free standing house or part of a block.
Thanks a lot for any tips!


You need to accumulate the total number of edges per island and multiply it by the result you previously had

This setup will output the total amount of edges per island that are in the selection

In order to get the total number of edges in the selection for each mesh island, this setup is enough


Thank you! But.. it still gives the total of number of edges or am I using it wrong? For the examples, both faces/islands should give back 2: since there are two edges on the face that met the earlier criterium. I really just need the count of the edges in that pink selection

I think I got it! For the first example, I also connected the boolean to the Accumulate Field Group ID input, you might have missed that? And then, without the Multiply, every edge says the number of edges in the island that meet the criterium. Then I used store named attribute (integer, face), and now every face has the number of edges as an attribute!

@CubeyQB Oh, my bad, I thought you wanted to get the total number of edges for each mesh island that had at least an edge affected by the boolean selection, I see you've figured it out but I'll update the answer anyway

Based on Alex's answer, this is how I build it:
Connect boolean output with accumulate field (as Value), connect Mesh Island Island Index into Group ID, then connect Accumulate field to Store named Attribute (Integer, Face).
(The extrude mesh isn't shown in the pictures, just for control)
Thanks for the input!


